# three.js first-person-controle makes objects disappears from scene

Tags: webgl, three.js

Please have look at the following Three.js snippet  http://jsfiddle.net/ahmedadel/GUr6y/3/ ,
the problem is the objects disappears from the scene after any navigation event (w a s d) or click if the camera attached to FirstPersonControls

```
controls = new THREE.FirstPersonControls(camera);
```

any help solving this ?
thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I remember first person controls look along the z axis..

So try changing that

```
camera.position.z = 1000
```

to

```
camera.position.y = 1000;
```

Which means you would be 1000 off the ground. That JS fiddle won't load so I cant test it.

Though looks like your cube is rendered at 0; try:

```
camera.position.z = 100;
camera.position.x = -1000;
```

then do

```
camera.lookAt(mesh);
```

Once you have created the cube.

Comment: i am sorry this dosnt helped

Comment: Did you try it outside of JS fiddle.. I notice on JS fiddle if you log the camera position it was coming out as NAN,NAN,NAN